# Timeout for Lambda: Export Cloudfront logs from S3 to ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I wrote a Lambda function to send Cloudfront logs into Elasticsearch. 
The worklow is as follow: 
1. Cloudfront send logs (compressed into `.gz` format) into S3 
2. The Bucket send a notification which is caught by the Lambda function 
3. The Lambda is triggered. Decompress the logs and send them into Elasticsearch.

I use for this [s3-to-logstore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-to-logstore) combined with [winston-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston).

The Lambda is indeed triggered, but only **one** part of the logs is sent to Elasticsearch, because the Lambda function times out (I set the timeout to the max: 5min).

I suspect decompressing the `.gz` logs take some time, but it's at most `30 KB` which is not much and should not take long.

I was inspired by this [example](https://github.com/qixotic/s3-to-logstore/blob/master/examples/loggly.js), and here is my function:

```
var s3ToLogstore = require('s3-to-logstore');
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-elasticsearch');

var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: process.env.ES_HOST,
  log: 'trace'
});

var transport = new winston.transports.Elasticsearch({
  indexPrefix: process.env.ES_INDEXPREFIX,
  client: client
});

var options = {
  format: process.env.FORMAT,
  transport: transport,
  reformatter: function(data){
    data.environment = process.env.STAGE;
    data.origin = process.env.FORMAT;
    return data;
  }
};

exports.handler = s3ToLogstore(options);
```

The cloudwatch logs are totally fine, and there is no error in them. The Lambda just times out, and I can't figure out why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the elasticsearch client keeps a connection open, so the lambda never stops. Try setting keepAlive property to false.

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: process.env.ES_HOST,
  log: 'trace',
  keepAlive: false
});
```

Refer to keepAlive and related properties.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. I did that, but I still get times out error.